# Why parent process reads first from pipe in LINUX

Tags: c, linux

i have run this code and found out that the parent process reads first then child process writes. i want to know why this is happening? 
 Additionally i also want to know how can i use two pipes in this program.i just want the concept, any code will be appreciated.Thanks

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    main()
    {
            int     fd[2];
            pid_t   childpid;

            pipe(fd);

            if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
            {
                    perror("fork");

            }

            if(childpid == 0)
            {
                    /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
                    close(fd[0]);
        printf("\nChild writes\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                    /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
                    close(fd[1]);
        printf("parent reads\n\n");
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: why should child be first? As parent starts before child it is likely that it will reach the `if(childpid == 0)` first. You need to make him wait for the child.

Comment: how can i use 2 pipes and 2 chidren within the program

Answer (score 2):

For you queries :-

***The parent process reads first then child process writes. i want to know why this is happening***?

After fork() both process work independently, so which process will be scheduled first, it's depend on scheduler.

***How can i use two pipes in this program?***

open two pipe, one for parents and one for child process. because pipe are unidirectional.

```
int fd[2];
int fd1[2];

parents will write on fd[1]  child will read from fd[0]
child will write on fd1[1] parents will read from fd1[0]
```